# understand the use of Websphere shared libraries vs. having libraries defined in your java project?

Tags: java, websphere, shared-libraries

Can someone help me understand the use of Websphere shared libraries vs. having libraries defined in your java project? I'm new to websphere and don't understand the concept of shared libraries vs just putting the library classes in the lib folder in the project you are working on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several benefits to using shared libraries:

1. Reduce memory consumption.  If you have many applications, using a server-associated shared library or isolated shared library allows the JVM to load a single copy of the classes in memory rather than loading the classes for each copy of the library in an application.
2. Reduce the size of your WAR.  This can improve deployment times, reduce network transfer, and reduce storage sizes if you keep backups.
3. Improve manageability of environment.  If you have many applications deployed and need to upgrade one of the libraries due to a fix, it can be more effort to repackage/redeploy many applications than to update a central library.  If you need to update applications "slowly" rather than all at once, you can declare multiple shared libraries for different versions of the dependency; this approach obviously requires using application-associated rather than server-associated libraries, so you'll need to use an isolated shared library to still get the other benefits listed here.
4. Better support for native libraries.  If your application requires a library that uses native libraries and you package the library in your application, then you are typically unable to restart only your application without restarting the server since there is a JVM restriction that prevents native libraries from being unloaded or being loaded by multiple applications.

The downside is that applications typically have tight coupling to the version of the library they are using, so separating the libraries from the application can make upgrades more difficult.

Comment: If this answered your question, you should click the checkmark to the left of the answer. This increases my reputation, and it increases your acceptance rate, which makes it more likely people will answer your questions in the future.

Comment: Potential downside of #1: some libraries don't seem to work well if they're shared across apps. At least log4j caused us issues that way in the past. On the other hand, if you use Application-associated, that seems to work, but then doesn't have benefit #1 :-)

Comment: Yes, you're right, some libraries are sensitive to their hosting class loader and cannot be isolated from the application.

Answer (score 2):

Brett brought up valid points. I'll add more detail for the downside of #3.

For #3 upgrading libraries to a new version like the example due to a fix is a benefit. However, in my experience if there are several applications sharing the same JVM in production and they all use the library it becomes difficult to (a) test all the applications with the new version of the library (b) in a timely manner and (c) get all the stakeholders to agree to the library fix to be deployed especially if they are in different business units. Though applications can override parent libraries by setting their classloader policy to parent-last which means those applications that need to integrate the latest fix can do so within their EAR file and override the shared library. But then that defeats the benefits of the shared library. It boils down to how "shared" the JVM environment is and whether those applications in the same JVM are able to consume a new version of a library in a timely manner (i.e. get through their testing).

Comment: If you use application-associated shared libraries (rather than server-associated), you can declare multiple shared libraries for different versions of the dependency and then slowly update the applications one at a time.  With that approach, you can still get all the other benefits of shared libraries (though you'll need to use isolated shared libraries to get the memory consumption benefits).

Comment: (I've updated my answer to incorporate your feedback, thanks.)